# How to integrate openfient in a Quiz app in objective c Cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in objective c and want to integrate openfient in my quiz applicaion.

Please advise me how to integrate it.

Thanks 
Shivam S.kara

Answer (score 2):

Internet is full of good tutorials, this are just the first results:

[iPhone SDK- How To Integrate OpenFeint Into Your Application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEhcpIKvKdg)

[Openfeint integration](http://www.mycodestudio.com/blog/2009/12/01/openfeint-integration/)

[creating an OpenFeint iPhone app from scratch](http://vimeo.com/5633994)

Google is your friend ;)